# SQL Server Replication Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have setup 'Transactional with Queued updating' between 2 machines.
If there is a database crash in the publisher machine, a database restore is needed. Due to time gap, there will have records already in the subscriber, but NOT found in the database backup.

how can i configure, so that once restore db and replication setup again in Pulbisher machine, the records in the subscribers will sync back to publishers so that there is nothing loss in publisher side ?

Thanks.

Comment: what replication you are using ? what does this mean `Transactional with Queued updating`

Comment: It is the Updatable Subscriptions for Transactional Replication.
Data changed in publisher is replicated to Subscriber, vice versa.